# Dynamically change table cell with user input in Javascript

Tags: javascript, input, dynamic, html-table, cell

This is what I'm trying to do: I have a table, created from Javascript with user input in each cell.  This table is just to confirm that the data entered by the user is correct. If the user sees an error, they click on the cell which needs editing, and it puts a textbox in the table cell with the current cell data. The user will then be able to submit changes or discard the changes if they clicked on the wrong cell. This is currently what I have:

```
    <table id = "confirm">
      <tr><th>Firstname</th><td id = "txtFirstname" onclick = "update(this.id)">Adan</td></tr>
      <tr><th>Lastname</th><td>Smith</td></tr>
      <tr><th>Username</th><td>ASmith</td></tr>
      <tr><th>Email</th><td>abc@123.com</td></tr>
      <tr><th>Phone</th><td>123-456-7890</td></tr>
    </table>

<script type = "text/javascript">
  function update(id){
    //Get contents off cell clicked
    var content = document.getElementById(id).firstChild.nodeValue;
    //Switch to text input field
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "<input type = 'text' name = 'txtNewInput' id = 'txtNewInput' value = '" + content + "'/>";
  }
</script>
```

This is what my current code does: When user clicks on the cell, it replaces it with the current text inside a textbox, which is great, but when you try to edit the text, it calls the function over again replacing the text with "null". Please help me figure this out!

Comment: [Bubbling](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is caused by [event bubbling](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html). You didn't want `onclick` to apply to `input`, but unfortunately this is not the case. To solve this problem, simply do this (taken from http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/McJ4s/)

```css
table td, th{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table id="confirm">
    <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <td contentEditable>Adan</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <td>Smith</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Username</th>
        <td>ASmith</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Email</th>
        <td>abc@123.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Phone</th>
        <td>123-456-7890</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Why do it with JavaScript when [simple HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Content_Editable) can do the same thing? `;)`

---

## Internet Explorer:

There is a strange "bug" in IE that it won't allow a table cell to be editable <sup><sub>(why, Microsoft?)</sub></sup> So you have to wrap your content with a `<div>` (taken from http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/McJ4s/3/):

```css
table td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table id="confirm">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <td>
      <div contenteditable>Adan</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <td>Smith</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Username</th>
    <td>ASmith</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Email</th>
    <td>abc@123.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Phone</th>
    <td>123-456-7890</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Great! Didn't know that attribute yet.

Comment: @Flauwekeul - Actually `contentEditable` has been around since IE6, it is almost `13` years ago.

Comment: @user2052072 - Stupid IE, creating headaches and issues since 2001. Try this one: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/McJ4s/3/

Comment: So, it has to be in a div element? Thanks!, I also figured it out using my method as well. Took quite a bit of time, but mission accomplished.

Comment: @Vince - It can be any element except `td` or `tr`.

Comment: That is nice to know, I will use that for future reference. That may be a handy attribute for me later.

Comment: I am creating a dynamic table using JS how can i edit each cell ? here is my code 'row.insertCell(0).innerHTML= firstname.value;'

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> <table id = "confirm">
>       <tr><th>Firstname</th><td id = "txtFirstname" onclick = "update(this.id)">Adan</td></tr>
>       <tr><th>Lastname</th><td>Smith</td></tr>
>       <tr><th>Username</th><td>ASmith</td></tr>
>       <tr><th>Email</th><td>abc@123.com</td></tr>
>       <tr><th>Phone</th><td>123-456-7890</td></tr>
>     </table>
>
> <script type = "text/javascript">
>   function update(id){
>     //Get contents off cell clicked
>     var content = document.getElementById(id).firstChild.nodeValue;
>     //Switch to text input field
>     document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "<input type = 'text' name = 'txtNewInput' id = 'txtNewInput' value = '" + content + "'/>";
>   }
> </script>
> ```

Added an if statement in the update() function. Changed it to:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
  function update(id){
    if(document.getElementById(id).firstChild != "[object HTMLInputElement]"){
      //Get contents off cell clicked
      var content = document.getElementById(id).firstChild.nodeValue;
      //Switch to text input field
      document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "<input type = 'text' name = 'txtNewInput' id = 'txtNewInput' value = '" + content + "'/>";
    }
  }
</script>
```

That works like a charm!

Comment: Your code is a bit long and messy. jQuery might be a better option here: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/McJ4s/5/

Comment: I'm avoiding jquery as I'm not too familiar with it. But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

```
    var table = document.getElementById('');
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var noRowSelected = 1;
    for(var i=1; i<rowCount; i++) {
            var row = table.rows[i];
            var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
            if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
                if(rowCount <= 1) {
                   break;
                }
                document.getElementById("").value = row.cells[1].innerHTML;
                document.getElementById("").value = row.cells[2].innerHTML;
                document.getElementById("").value = row.cells[3].innerHTML;
                document.getElementById("").value = row.cells[4].innerHTML;
           }
       }

  The Above Example the checkbox must be need for the each row.then we used this check box to get the current edit row values in the dynamic table. then to use the id for edit field to set valued got from the table.
```

Answer (score 0):

**Dynamically Change the Table Row Value:**

var table = document.getElementById('');

```
var rowCount = table.rows.length;

var noRowSelected = 1;

for(var i=1; i<rowCount; i++) {
        var row = table.rows[i];
        var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
        if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
            if(rowCount <= 1) {
               break;
            }
            document.getElementById("").value = row.cells[1].innerHTML;
            document.getElementById("").value = row.cells[2].innerHTML;
            document.getElementById("").value = row.cells[3].innerHTML;
            document.getElementById("").value = row.cells[4].innerHTML;
       }
   }
```

The Above Example the checkbox must be need for the each row.then we used this check box to get the current edit row values in the dynamic table.